# Getting touch events when objects have an alpha of 0 In Corona SDK

Tags: events, lua, alpha, coronasdk

If I wanted to have an invisible box, for example, how could I get touch events if it has an alpha of 0? Or is there another way to make an invisible box.

```
local function invisiblebuttontouch(event)
    if event.phase == 'began' then
        print (event.x..","..event.y)
    end
end

button = display.newRect(1,1,300,300)
button:addEventListener("touch",invisiblebuttontouch)
button.alpha = 0
```

It never prints out the x and y, however if I don't set the alpha to 0, then it works fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add this line to your code:

```
button.isHitTestable = true
```

Source: http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/DisplayObject/isHitTestable.html

Answer (score 2):

it should be noted that no callback for a target will be fired if one of the parent groups are invisible disregarding isHittestable. Also setting isHittestable of the mother group won't change that.